# How to install Susy 2 using npm for use with gulp

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass, susy-compass, susy, susy-sass

According to [the Susy 2.1.2 documentation](https://susy.readthedocs.io/install/), installing Susy is as simple as running `npm install susy --save-dev` then altering your Gulpfile in accordance with the afore-mentioned doc. You might suspect this would install 2.1.2.

However, this operation installs Susy 3. Susy 3 introduced breaking changes compared to Susy 2, which is preventing my client's SASS code from compiling. There is no documentation for how to install Susy 2 in the Susy 3 docs.

How can I install Susy 2 using npm for use with Gulp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to force susy to stay in 2.x you can run

```
npm install --save susy@2.x
```

this will install the latest version of 2.x but not 3.x+

Answer (score 0):

The answer was quite obvious in hindsight. In package.json, change `"susy": "^3.1.6"` to `"Susy": "2.2.14"`. Remove the susy directory in node_modules, then run `npm install` again.